# How to detect which picture is clicked in a cell of a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tablecell

I display 5 thumbnails in every table cell. So how do I know which picture is clicked by the user?  It's easy to know which line is selected, but I don't know how to convert the touch point to the coordinate in tablecell.

Comment: Instead of `UIImageView` use `UIButton` for your every thumbnail and add selector to each of them

Comment: You can add tap gesture on UIImageView and the selector method will called when user will tap on any thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `UICollectionView` in every table view cell(for those images).And then implement `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use tag. For each UIImageView in your cell, you can assign a tag using storyboard. You then add TapGestureRecognizer for each of the UIImageView. Next, get the tag by:

```
- (void)imageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     UIView *view = sender.view; 
     NSLog(@"%d", view.tag);//By tag, you can find out where you had tapped. 
     if(view.tag == 101){
        //first image is tapped
     }else if(view.tag == 102){
        //second image is tapped
     }
}
```

Use the tag to identify which image is being tapped.
Hope it helps

Comment: only a few img worked.  
`tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTap:)];
 [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];   [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;   
   while(...)
{
             img.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imgFilePath];
                    img.tag = [imgNo intValue];
                    img.userInteractionEnabled = true;
                    [img addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}
- (void)imageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{}`

Comment: You need to create multiple tap gesture recognizer. One recognizer can only be used for one imageview